Dynamic icon Android issue
I'm implementing dynamic icon feature in the flutter project using dynamic_icon_lus plugin
On IOS everything works great. On Android and issue appears when I'm launching the app in debug mode from Android studio over the existing debug app with dynamically changed icon.
The configured activity alias looks like this
    <!-- Alternate Icons -->
    <activity-alias
        android:name="${applicationId}.BlackFriday"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/alternative_launcher_icon"
        android:label="${appName}"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
            />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity-alias>

So I'm able to launch app first time from Android studio. Then the call
    await FlutterDynamicIconPlus.setAlternateIconName(
      iconName: alternativeIcon.isEmpty ? null : alternativeIcon,
      isSilent: true,
      blacklistBrands: ['Redmi'],
      blacklistManufactures: ['Xiaomi'],
      blacklistModels: ['Redmi 200A'],
    );

happens, where alternativeIcon = "BlackFriday".
I'm killing app manually and I can see the launch icon changes.
I launch app again from Android studio and can see the error
2024-11-27 11:40:52.822 11968-11968 AndroidRuntime pid-11968 E  
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.eyewa.app.dev, PID: 11968 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.eyewa.app.dev/com.eyewa.app.dev.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.eyewa.app.dev.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~_gALSD2nZU7TZ7i3mJtlwg==/com.eyewa.app.dev-2YbCJicUl2b2LiIMvrYBCw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~_gALSD2nZU7TZ7i3mJtlwg==/com.eyewa.app.dev-2YbCJicUl2b2LiIMvrYBCw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~_gALSD2nZU7TZ7i3mJtlwg==/com.eyewa.app.dev-2YbCJicUl2b2LiIMvrYBCw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4048)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4312)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2571)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
                                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.eyewa.app.dev.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~_gALSD2nZU7TZ7i3mJtlwg==/com.eyewa.app.dev-2YbCJicUl2b2LiIMvrYBCw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~_gALSD2nZU7TZ7i3mJtlwg==/com.eyewa.app.dev-2YbCJicUl2b2LiIMvrYBCw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~_gALSD2nZU7TZ7i3mJtlwg==/com.eyewa.app.dev-2YbCJicUl2b2LiIMvrYBCw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:637)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1328)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4035)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4312) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2571) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067) 

I appreciate any advice or comment.

The package page you linked states Supports only iOS (with version > 10.  It wont work on android.

I guess they not consistend with the support message. In metadata you can see that
"A flutter plugin for dynamically changing app icon, support IOS version > 10.3 and Android"

It supports Android - you can see it from the example configuration and from the repository
